# How to read csv data one by one and pass it in multiple testNG tests

Tags: csv, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I need to insert a data multiple times in an web application. I am using selenium with testNG along with data driven framework.

I am using CSV file for reading the the input values.

Please find the sample code below.

```
public class TestData
{
 private static String firstName;
 
 public static String lastName;
 
 @BeforeClass
 public void beforeClass() throws IOException
 {
    
     reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    
     while((record = reader.readNext()) != null) 
     { 
        firstName = record[0];  
        lastName = record[1];  
     }
    
  }
 
 @Test
 public void test1()
 {
     driver.findElement(By.id(id)).sendKeys(firstName);
    
     driver.findElement(By.id(id)).click();
    
     and so on....
    
 }

 @Test
 public void test2()
 {
     driver.findElement(By.id(id)).sendKeys(lastName);
    
     driver.findElement(By.id(id)).click();
    
     and so on....
 }

}
```

Here, I need to insert 3 records, but when I use the above code, only the 3rd record gets inserted.

Kindly help me to fix this issue.

**Sample Input File**

[image]

Comment: `beforeClass` reads ALL rows in the file before returning (while loop does this). So you will always have only the last row of data. You could save the CSV data in an array and access it by index within each test.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is a `Factory` powered by a `DataProvider`. The `Factory` would produce test class instances (A test class here is basically a regular class that contains one or more `@Test` methods housed in it). The data provider would basically feed the factory method with the data required to instantiate the test class.

Now your `@Test` methods would basically work with the data members in the instances to run its logic.

Here's a simple sample that shows this in action.

```java
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClassSample {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Factory(dataProvider = "dp")
    public TestClassSample(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "dp")
    public static Object[][] getData() {
        //feel free to replace this with the logic that reads up a csv file (using CSVReader)
        // and then translates it to a 2D array.
        return new Object[][]{
                {"Mohan", "Kumar"},
                {"Kane", "Williams"},
                {"Mark", "Henry"}
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Assertions.assertThat(this.firstName).isNotEmpty();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        Assertions.assertThat(this.lastName).isNotEmpty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the data given by you , the while loop ends at the third record of CSV file. In each iteration your variables "firstName" and "lastName" are overwritten.

When the loop breaks , the variables store the lastly written values. So , use a better data structure for storing all values. I recommend **map**.

You can further club all the test cases in a single method , use *invocationcount* attribute in **@Test** annotation to repeat the execution for each entry from **map**.  Add one more method with **@BeforeTest** for increment to next keyset in map.